# Width of shading lines in barplot

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart

I created a barplot with the following script in R:

```
bars <- c(229, 158)
shading.lines <- c(83, 83)
years <- c("1985-89", "2017")
cols1 <- c("indianred4","green4")
cols2 <- c("green4","indianred4")
barplot(bars,names.arg=years,col=cols1)
barplot(shading.lines,names.arg=NA,col=cols2,density=11,add=T)
```

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the width of the shading lines? I`d like to have them thicker in order to get the same appeareance of the shaded part in 1985-89 and 2017.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @ Jaap: Sorry, I accidentally closed the tab while creating this question. It was then posted to stackoverflow, apparently. This was not my aim, I will post it again when edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the width of shading using `par(lwd=...)`:

```
bars <- c(229, 158)
shading.lines <- c(83, 83)
years <- c("1985-89", "2017")
cols1 <- c("indianred4","green4")
cols2 <- c("green4","indianred4")
barplot(bars,names.arg=years,col=cols1)
# Set width of shading
par(lwd=5)
barplot(shading.lines,names.arg=NA,col=cols2,density=11,add=T)
# Set width of shading to the default value
par(lwd=1)
```

[image]

Comment: This has set the width of the box too, which is not always desired. Any solution?

Comment: I've found a solution: plot separately the box and the shading lines, with `add=T` and `border=NA` for the second barplot. Use `par(lwd=5)` in between.